# Why are default values for PostgreSQL on insert not working?

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert, popsql

I have a PostgreSQL database on Heroku and I've connected to that using PopSQL. Here is the model for the table (using Flask + SQLAlchemy) -

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    email = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    group = Column(String)
    age = Column(String)
    gender = Column(String)
    category = Column(String)

    isEnrolled = Column(Boolean)
    logCount = Column(Integer, default=0)

    logged = Column(ARRAY(Boolean), default=[None]*14)
    medMin = Column(ARRAY(Integer), default=[None]*14)


    def __init__(self, email, age, group ,gender, category):
        self.email = email
        self.age = age
        self.group = group
        self.gender = gender
        self.category = category
```

The table was created using `db.create_all()`

In PopSQL, when I do an INSERT of the form:

```
INSERT INTO users(email,"group",age,gender,category)
VALUES('abc@gmail.com','other','20-30','Female','intrinsic');
```

The columns of logCount, logged and medMin are set to `null` and not their default values. Why is this happening?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the `CREATE TABLE` statement for the `users` table

Comment: Your defaults are applied by the model.  If you don't go through the model, you don't get the default.  Maybe you can specify a 'server_default' instead.

Comment: @jjanes is correct - see https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html?highlight=server_default#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.server_default